# How I can open google authenticator on iframe, not on pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api

I'm trying, but I still have not been successful. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? It's possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open Google Authenticator in an `<iframe>`, only a popup.

This is a restriction put in place by Google to prevent **[clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)**.